# Dired move file with quotation

Tags: dired, filenames

When I do `dired-do-copy` on a file with a quotation for example `"test"f.txt`,

I get the following error when copying/moving file with quotation symbols

```
Copy ‘/home/user/Music/"test"f.txt’ to ‘/media/user/Audio/"test"f.txt’ failed:
(file-missing Opening output file No such file or directory /media/user/Audio/"test"f.txt)
```

The above behaviour is same for `dired-do-rename` when moving file to a directory.

Is there a way for `dired` to escape special characters or do I need to rename files?

Comment: Does `/media/user/Audio/` exist? maybe you meant `/home/user/Audio/`?

Comment: This should work.